# Train tickets from Brussels Airport to Brugges

Tags: trains, airport-transfer, brussels, bru, bruges

It is my first question here:

I was looking on [the Belgian Rail website](http://www.belgianrail.be/) to get a ticket to Brugge from Brussel-Nat-Luchthaven. I suppose, It is in the airport

Well, when I am looking the tickets they show me several options with different combinations and stops. But When I try to buy it, the tickets don't have any hour/time related. I can get any train, any combination. Keep in mind that all tickets have the same price.

A bonus track, I arrive in  'Zaventem airport'. Anybody knows if the station is in the same airport. In the map look very close.

I hope you don't consider duplicate than [Train from Brussels to Bruges](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/37023/train-from-brussels-to-bruges)

Comment: I removed the sentence asking for “any suggestions”. It's too open-ended for this site and already answered in the other question. My answer covers the part of your question that are new.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zaventem is the name of the town where the airport is located, which is why it's often called Zaventem airport. Its official name is now Bruxelles-National/Brussel-Nationaal but this is the same airport. “Brussel-Nationaal-Luchthaven” (literally “Brussels-National-Airport”) is the train station designed to serve it.

Another potential source of confusion is the “Zaventem” train station (not really a station but more a stop with no services now). It's another station in the same town, not very far obviously, but it does not serve the airport (and in fact receives very few trains).

Unlike long-distance high-speed trains in countries like France or Spain, most trains in Belgium indeed have few restrictions, you just buy a ticket and use it on any train like a metro/tramway ticket. As long as it covers your route (including the Diabolo fee where applicable), it's OK. Reserving a seat or getting a discount because you're willing to commit to a specific train isn't even an option, like it might be in Germany for example.

Comment: The civilian passenger terminal is in the municipality of Zaventem. The whole airport stretches over three municipalities: Zaventem, Steenokkerzeel and Machelen.

Comment: @AndréPeseur Right, meanwhile “the airport is located in Zaventem” is a perfectly reasonable summary for the purpose of this question…

Comment: Your answer correct. I just wanted to add this piece of information for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 3):

The "Zaventem airport' station is in the airport itself. When you do the search, than the name will be corrected to Brussel-Nationaal Luchthaven or just Brussel-Nat-Luchthaven.

The trains in belgium, except for a few special services, like thalys, don't have sit / train reservation. You can get any train.

The only detail that you must have in account is that to the airport you pay a an extra fee called "diabolo fee". If you buy the ticket in the machine or online it's usually included.

Comment: Nope. The Zaventem station is not in the airport.

Comment: The station in the airport is called BRUXELLES-NATIONAL-AEROPORT in French and BRUSSEL-NATIONAAL-LUCHTHAAVEN in Dutch

Comment: @AndréPeseur I didnt say Zaventem station is in the airport, I said that "Zaventem airport" station refers to the same station as the airport station if you search in the Belgium train website. The name even gets corrected after you press the search button.

Comment: The first version of your answer was confusing. Now it is slightly better.